part NCC aircrafts in europe and pilots flying with FAA licenses
Good morning,
i know that since 2020,2021,   FCL licenses are necessary for an european pilot to fly an aircraft registered in a third country BUT based in France with part NCC; it seems that we can have a validation of an FAA license for one year, and another year if we follow a formation to get the EASA CPL IR exams...
my 2 questions are :
Is the request for the validation is difficult to obtain with the French DGAC ?
And what about a non european resident flying this aircraf with only FAA licenses ?
Thank you for your cooperation
Regards
